# Android FragmentTransaction commit twice

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to Android Developing and i'm trying to create a clickable ListView. And when you click on any element of it, it shows a fragment with the text from elememnt. But it doesn't seem to work becouse you can't commit FragmentTransaction twice. And without first commiting you can't add a fragment to fragment contrainer and therefore you can't change the text of Fragment=(

Here's my Activity Code:

```
   public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        Random rand = new Random(); // Randomizer
        ArrayList Array = new ArrayList(5); // Array
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Array.add(rand.nextInt(30));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> MyAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Array);
        final ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.MyList);
        listview.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
        final MyFragment MyFrag = new MyFragment();
        fTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer, MyFrag);
        fTransaction.commit();
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String Selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                MyFrag.SetText(Selection);
                fTransaction.remove(MyFrag);
                fTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer, MyFrag);
                fTransaction.commit();
            }
        };
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
    }
```

I've tried to use "replace" but the result was the same...
It says:

```
" java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called "
```

Here is my fragment code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_first, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.MyFragView);
        if (textView == null)
        {
            System.out.println("myInflatedView == null");
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_first, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach( Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have attached a fragment",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void SetText(String text)
    {

        if(textView == null)
        {
            System.out.println("textView == null");
        }
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Sry for a huge pack of hard-reading code=(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initiate a new transaction, not use the previous because you have already commit it.

Comment: Like this: `FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();` ?

Comment: Right. In your case, you must create a new transaction every time you click on an item. You can't reuse a transaction after you commit it (i think)

Comment: Well...Now i've initiated a new fragTransaction...Then i've replaced my fragment...and it doesn't work=/ No errors, but it doesnt change the text of fragment. Do you have any ideas why?=( Thx for the help, btw.

Comment: Are you creating a new fragment? Or using the one you removed? Try create a new one. You could also try to communicate with the fragment to update the data in it, but that depends of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Everything works fine with attaching a second fragment. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

well, you should create new `FragmentTransaction` inside the `onItemClick` which will remove the old fragment